# How to print a PDF file showing the print dialog directly from my macOS application?

Tags: macos, pdf, printing

I would like to be able to display a macOS print dialog for printing a PDF file directly from my application. Is there a way to do this?

Here are some solutions that don't quite meet my needs:

- I can use AppleScript to ask the Preview application to open the PDF
  file and display a print dialog. This is very close. The problem is
  that the user sees the document displayed in a Preview window while
  the print dialog is open. I would prefer that the print dialog be
  displayed on my application or in isolation.
- I can use various terminal commands to print the PDF file without any
  user interaction. The problem is that I want the user to be able to
  interact with the print dialog.
- I can use the [AppKit printing API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printingapi/osxp_printingapi.html) to display a print dialog from my application. The problem is that the only way I see to actually print the content is to render it in a View.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem you are having with the AppKit printing API.  The following snippet of code should give you a print dialog box without a View of the document.

```
    Boolean accepted = true;

    NSPrintInfo *thePrintInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];

    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    NSPrintPanel *printPanel = [NSPrintPanel printPanel];
    accepted = [printPanel runModalWithPrintInfo: thePrintInfo];
```

Comment: What happens next? At what point do I supply the PDF file?

Comment: In my case, I had already gotten the PDF document the user wanted to print via the command line.  All I am doing here is gathering information from the print dialog box to feed into our APDFL program.  The full sample we have can be seen here if it helps.  https://github.com/datalogics/apdfl-cplusplus-samples/blob/develop/Printing/PDFPrintGUI/PDFPrintGUI.cpp